# what is wrong in this why new font is not working?

Tags: vb.net

The following code am using for the font , but it is not working can anyone please help.

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox1.Font = new Font(TextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
End Sub
```

Comment: value of type 'fontinfo' cannot be converted to 'font'

Comment: there is no reason from the above func that the font shouldn't be changing to `bold` perhaps your error is from somewhere else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet like yours is working for me and I can't reproduce the mentioned error message.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Font = New Font(TextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = "StackOverflow"
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

> value of type 'fontinfo' cannot be converted to 'font'

[FontInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) is a class in the System.Web.dll.

Assuming that `TextBox1` is a [System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.7.2) for which its [Font Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.font?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_Font) is of type `FontInfo`, the problem becomes obvious.

The code `new Font(TextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)` is trying to create a [System.Drawing.Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Font__ctor_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_FontStyle_) instance.  Such code would be correct for a WinForm project, but not an Asp.Net project.

The correct statement would be:

```
TextBox1.Font.Bold = True
```